# Why is the default constructor deleted in derived class?

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
    T tVar;
public:
    Foo(T t) : tVar(t) {}
};

class FooDerived : public Foo<std::string> {};

int main()
{
    FooDerived d;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives:

> Error (active)    E1790   the default constructor of "FooDerived" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function    cpp89   d:\Dokumentumok2\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\cpp89\cpp89\cpp89.cpp  20

It compiles if I add a default constructor to class `Foo`. Could someone please explain this? This was a question in an interview test. Thank you.

Comment: how should the default constructor construct a `Foo` when you dont pass a paraeter?

Comment: What do you expect the value of Foo::tVar to be when that code is run?

Comment: You can bring back the default ctor if you want it (and you know it'll work for your purposes) with `= default`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you don't declare any constructors, the compiler implicitly declares a default constructor for you with `public` access, unless it is ill-formed.

Also, when you explicitly declare any constructors, the default constructor is implicitly deleted.

```
class FooDerived : public Foo<std::string> {};
```

is equivalent to:

```
class FooDerived : public Foo<std::string>
{
   public:
      FooDerived() : Foo<std::string>() {}
};
```

As you can see, that is a problem since `Foo<std::string>` does not have a default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any default constructor in Foo class. As you have added a parameterized constructor in Foo, so the compiler will not provide the default constructor.

Unless specified, the derived class will call the default constructor of the base class (one without the parameters).

Hence, you see the error.

Answer (score 0):

working example.
once you declare the Foo constructor that accept a parameter then the default empty constructor is deleted.

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
    T tVar;
public:
    Foo(T t) : tVar(t) {}
};

class FooDerived : public Foo<std::string> {
public:
    FooDerived():Foo<std::string>(""){}
};

int main()
{
    FooDerived d;
    return 0;
}
```